# "Не с одной из сторон" или "ни с одной из сторон"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, частица-не, не-или-ни, частицы

Читаю одного из современных авторов. Нахожу: "Сбросив с плеча ружьё, он опустился на четвереньки, и тут услышал едва различимые человеческие голоса, которые доносились до него **не спереди и не сзади, не с одной из сторон,** а словно бы из-под земли".

Правильно ли автор употребил здесь частицы? И по поводу запятых меня терзают смутные сомнения, честно говоря. Подскажите, как правильно.

Comment: Для "ни" нужен глагол с "не" (*ни с одной из сторон не доносились*).

Answer (score 4):

Частицы употреблены правильно.

"Не" и "ни" отличаются по смыслу. Если понимать разницу в смысле, то сразу ясно, где должно быть "ни", а где "не".

"Не" – это просто отрицание. Пример: *Я еду не домой*. Что значит? Во-первых, что я еду. Во-вторых, что место назначения – не дом. А могу ли я добавить отрицание еще одного места назначения? Конечно: *Я еду не домой и не в спортзал*. "Не" от этого не превращается в "ни". Могу противопоставление добавить: *Я еду не домой, а на работу*. А с двумя отрицаниями будет: *Я еду не домой и не в спортзал, а на работу.*

У автора такая же конструкция только с тремя отрицаниями. Он там слышит звук не из А, не из В, не из С, а словно из-под земли.

Что касается "ни", то конструкция вида *ни А, ни В, ни С* означает *ничто и перечисленного* (то есть *ничто из А, В, С*).

И так же как с *ничто* (с *никто*, *никуда* и т.п.) глагол в этой конструкции должен быть отрицательным (то есть с "не").
Пример: *Я не еду ни домой, ни в спортзал.*
Может, я еду куда-то в другое место, а может, дома сижу – из этого предложения непонятно. Главное, что **никуда** из этих перечисленных мест я не еду.